# Entity Framework, code-first: combining master-detail with zero-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple master-detail relationship using code first EF:

```
public class User
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Tasks> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to modify it so that users can have a single, most important task. So I modify the User class to add it:

```
public class User
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Tasks> Tasks { get; set; }
     public string MostImportantTaskId { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("MostImportantTaskId")]
     public Task MostImportantTask { get; set; }
}
```

When I run `Add-Migration`, however, I get an unexpected result. EF is trying to add a `User_Id` column to the `Tasks` table, which I don't want, and dropping the foreign key I need for the master/detail relationship:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Tasks", "UserId", "dbo.Users");
    AddColumn("dbo.Tasks", "User_Id", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
    AddColumn("dbo.Users", "MostImportantTaskId", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
    CreateIndex("dbo.Tasks", "User_Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Users", "MostImportantTaskId");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Users", "MostImportantTaskId", "dbo.Tasks", "Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Tasks", "User_Id", "dbo.Users", "Id");
}

public override void Down()
{
    // ...
}
```

So how do I maintain the master detail relationship between users and tasks, while adding a reference to a single task to the `User` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not something I'm overly familiar with but I believe what you're looking for is `InverseProperty`. As your `User` class has multiple relationships with `Task`, you need to add the `InverseProperty` to your `Tasks` collection to point it to the `User` property on `Task`.

So if you make this change in your `User` class

```
[InverseProperty("User")]
public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
```

then when you run a migration the following code gets generated, which looks to be what you're after

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Users", "MostImportantTaskId", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
    CreateIndex("dbo.Users", "MostImportantTaskId");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Users", "MostImportantTaskId", "dbo.Tasks", "Id");
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Users", "MostImportantTaskId", "dbo.Tasks");
    DropIndex("dbo.Users", new[] { "MostImportantTaskId" });
    DropColumn("dbo.Users", "MostImportantTaskId");
}
```

Based on an example at [entityframeworktutorial.net](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

Note: I've assumed where you've referenced a `Tasks` class in your code it was a typo for `Task.`