# Why isn't EF Migrations generating the correct many-to-many relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have some EF Code First tables (one if them is ApplicationUser), and I'm trying to generate a migration to add a many-to-many relationship.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // many properties, not relevant here

    // NEW RELATIONSHIP
    public virtual ICollection<Trip> Trips { get; set; } = new HashSet<Trip>();
}

public class Trip
{
    // again, many properties

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ClientId))]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }

    public string PartnerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PartnerId))]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Partner { get; set; }

    // NEW RELATIONSHIP
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> OtherUsers { get; set; } = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();

}
```

Notice there's already a relationship in place (Trip has two foreign keys towards ApplicationUser, but I'm adding a new one.

When I run `Add-Migration Trips` in the console, this is generated:

```
public partial class Trips : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Trip_TripId", c => c.Int());
        AddColumn("dbo.Trips", "ApplicationUser_Id", c => c.String(maxLength: 128));
        CreateIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Trip_TripId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Trips", "ApplicationUser_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Trip_TripId", "dbo.Trips", "TripId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Trips", "ApplicationUser_Id", "dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Trips", "ApplicationUser_Id", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Trip_TripId", "dbo.Trips");
        DropIndex("dbo.Trips", new[] { "ApplicationUser_Id" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", new[] { "Trip_TripId" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Trips", "ApplicationUser_Id");
        DropColumn("dbo.AspNetUsers", "Trip_TripId");
    }
}
```

Why is it creating two one-to-many relationships instead of one many-to-many? I was expecting a third table to be generated.

I have done this before with no problem, but I don't know if the fact that I already have foreign keys is interfering with the generation.

I've seen [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382783/many-to-many-mapping-table) that solves this using the Fluent API, but I've never needed to use it before. Is it really the only way to solve it? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an `InverseProperty` on one of the new collections. Try changing your `Trip` class as follows

```
// NEW RELATIONSHIP
[InverseProperty("Trips")]
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> OtherUsers { get; set; } = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
```

That tells it the relationship is between the `OtherUsers` collection and the `Trips` property/collection.

More information at [Using both many-to-many and one-to-many to same entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228948/using-both-many-to-many-and-one-to-many-to-same-entity)

**Update:**
I notice the comments at the other question are ambiguous as to whether it works. I've not personally tried it with many-to-many relationships but this it works for situations such as [Entity Framework, code-first: combining master-detail with zero-to-one relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173788/entity-framework-code-first-combining-master-detail-with-zero-to-one-relations/38177081#38177081)

I've be interested to hear if it works in your case.

Comment: I'm still curious about why it doesn't detect it automatically, though.

Comment: With it being outside of conventions I expect they don't want to guess. Things could get muddled with multiple relationships between classes. Glad it worked though!